# Text next to image

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage, wrapfigure

I have a problem to get the following result in LaTeX:

[image]

The figure is not something I want to do with tikz, but I want to use `\includegraphics{figure1.png}`. Can someone help me to get this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is my proposal for your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics{figure1}
\caption{\label{fig:blue_rectangle} Rectangle}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item *Rectangle
\item *Color: blue
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

You can adapt the size of the two columns by playing with the `0.5\textwidth` part to have it matching your need (It does not have to be equal for the two columns!).

NOTE: The minipage environments must not have any uncommented whitelines between them, i.e. they must touching, as shown in the example. If there is a line between them, LaTeX draws them separately.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. But how can I alter the height of the text on the right (''*rectangle, *color:blue'') with respect to the height of the figure?

Comment: First of all you can use an option like this `\begin{minipage}[X]{}` where X is either t,c or b for top, center and bottom. You can also use the `\vspace{Yin}` or `\vspace{Zcm}` before the `\begin{itemize}` to add some space (Y inches or Z centimeters).

Comment: Thanks for your response. So how can I then indent my figure?

Comment: When you say indent, you mean have an "extra" margin? If that's it add `\hspace{}` with whatever you want before the first minipage (make sure to adapt the size of the minipage environments then not to have one going out of the page).

Answer (score 5):

EDITED to make rectangle, well... blue, per mrc's comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc,xcolor}
\begin{document}

%\def\x{\includegraphics{filename}}
\def\x{\textcolor{blue!70}{\rule{1in}{2in}}}
\def\y{\parbox[t]{1.5in}{\LARGE *Rectangle\\ {*Color: blue}}}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{\widthof{\y}}{0in}~
\raisebox{\baselineskip -\heightof{\x}}{\x} 
~\y
\caption{Rectangle}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, using the tabular:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3in}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5in}}
\centering
{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image} & Some text\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{The caption....}
\end{figure}
```

[image]