# How to align an image beside a text in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, itemize, minipage

I'm having some troubles with placing an image: I want to put the image by the side of the text but I'm obtaining this:

[image: gripper]

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{AG.jpg}
    \caption{Gripper}
    \label{img:g}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
\end{figure}
%
\vspace{-7cm}
%
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
%
%
\item[\textbf{\emph{Gripper}}] Un {\emph{gripper}$^{\href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQz5TQUep00}{1}}$} és un efector final que està dissenyat per a agafar i sostenir objectes. S'insereix en l'última baula del braç. Pot sostenir un objecte utilitzant diversos mètodes diferents, com ara: l'aplicació de pressió entre el que és "dits", o usar la magnetització o buit per contenir l'objecte, etc. Veure efector final.
%
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is that? Some sort of medieval torture device?!

Comment: you can see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119799/text-next-to-image or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55161/how-to-arrange-image-and-text-to-appear-side-by-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've finally solved it. I realized that I forgot the placement specifier. With

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
...
\end{figure}
```

it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhJMZ.jpg

Answer (score 4):

A much simpler way could be to simply put both, text and figure in a minipage and put these next to each other

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\textbf{\emph{Gripper}}] Un {\emph{gripper}} és un efector final que està dissenyat per a agafar i sostenir objectes. S'insereix en l'última baula del braç. Pot sostenir un objecte utilitzant diversos mètodes diferents, com ara: l'aplicació de pressió entre el que és "dits", o usar la magnetització o buit per contenir l'objecte, etc. Veure efector final.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{AG.jpg}
    \captionof{figure}{Gripper}
    \label{img:g}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

Notice that I did not use a figure-environment at all and replaced the `caption` with a `captionof` from the `caption`-package (the KOMA-classes have similar facilities).

Comment: Nice and simple solution!!