# how to insert my pic here?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, diagrams

how to insert my pic into the blank space,which i ticked in red circle.[image]
The pic i wanna insert is plotted by tikz .

---

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->] (0,0)--(0,2)node[above]{$y$};

\draw [->](1.5,0) arc(0:180:1.5);

\draw (-1.5,0)node[below]{-$a$} (1.5,0)node[below]{$a$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

here is my code

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3cm,top=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\item 判断$\iint\limits_Dln(x+y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$的符号。
\item 比较积分$\iint\limits_D ln(x+y)\mathrm{d}\sigma$与$\iint\limits_D[ln(x+y)]^2\mathrm{d}\sigma$的大小，其中D是三角形闭区域，三顶点各为(1,0)，(1,1)，(2,0)。
\item 计算\emph I=$\iint\limits_Dxy\mathrm{d}\sigma$，其中\emph D是直线y=1，x=2，及y=x所围的闭区域。
\item 计算$\iint\limits_Dxy\mathrm{d}\sigma$，其中D是抛物线$y^2=x$及直线y=x-2所围成的闭区域。
\item 求球体$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leqslant 4a^2$被圆柱面$x^2+y^2=2ax$，(a$>$0)所截得的面积(含在圆柱面内的部分)立体的体积。
\item 计算$\iint\limits_D\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}\sigma$，$D:x^2+y^2\leqslant1,x+y\geqslant1$。
\item 计算三重积分$\iiint\limits_{\Omega} z^2 \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$，其中$\Omega$是由椭球面$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}+ \frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$所围成的空间闭区域。
\item 计算\emph{I}=$\iiint\limits_{\Omega} z\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$，其中$\Omega$是球面$x^2+y^2+z^2=4\text{与}x^2+y^2=3z$所围的上部分。
\item 计算$\int_L\sqrt{y}\mathrm{d}s$，其中\emph L是抛物线$y=x^2$上点\emph{O}(0,0)与点\emph{B}(1,1)之间的一段弧。
\item 计算$\oint_\Gamma x^2\mathrm{d}s$，其中$\Gamma$为球面$x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$被平面$x+y+z=0$所截的圆周。
\item 计算$\int_Ly^2\mathrm{d}x$,其中\emph{L}为
(1)\quad半径为a圆心在原点的上半圆周，\\
方向为逆时针方向。\\
(2)\quad从点\emph{A}(a,0)沿x轴到点\emph{B}(-a,0)。
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Tip: to get proper code markup, select the code and hit Ctrl + K. That said, you can probably use two `minipage`s, similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234597/586

Comment: thank you i have already know how to markup @TorbjørnT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{multicol}` and modify as follows. In addition to the main problem, I recommend you to use nested enumeration instead of manually-created fake enumeration.

```
\item 
\begin{multicols}{2}
计算$\int_Ly^2\mathrm{d}x$,其中\emph{L}为
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 半径为a圆心在原点的上半圆周，方向为逆时针方向。
    \item 从点\emph{A}(a,0)沿x轴到点\emph{B}(-a,0)。
\end{enumerate}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0)--(0,2)node[above]{$y$};
    \draw [->](1.5,0) arc(0:180:1.5);
    \draw (-1.5,0)node[below]{-$a$} (1.5,0)node[below]{$a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3cm,top=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\item 判断$\iint\limits_Dln(x+y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$的符号。
\item 比较积分$\iint\limits_D ln(x+y)\mathrm{d}\sigma$与$\iint\limits_D[ln(x+y)]^2\mathrm{d}\sigma$的大小，其中D是三角形闭区域，三顶点各为(1,0)，(1,1)，(2,0)。
\item 计算\emph I=$\iint\limits_Dxy\mathrm{d}\sigma$，其中\emph D是直线y=1，x=2，及y=x所围的闭区域。
\item 计算$\iint\limits_Dxy\mathrm{d}\sigma$，其中D是抛物线$y^2=x$及直线y=x-2所围成的闭区域。
\item 求球体$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leqslant 4a^2$被圆柱面$x^2+y^2=2ax$，(a$>$0)所截得的面积(含在圆柱面内的部分)立体的体积。
\item 计算$\iint\limits_D\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm{d}\sigma$，$D:x^2+y^2\leqslant1,x+y\geqslant1$。
\item 计算三重积分$\iiint\limits_{\Omega} z^2 \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$，其中$\Omega$是由椭球面$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}+ \frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$所围成的空间闭区域。
\item 计算\emph{I}=$\iiint\limits_{\Omega} z\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$，其中$\Omega$是球面$x^2+y^2+z^2=4\text{与}x^2+y^2=3z$所围的上部分。
\item 计算$\int_L\sqrt{y}\mathrm{d}s$，其中\emph L是抛物线$y=x^2$上点\emph{O}(0,0)与点\emph{B}(1,1)之间的一段弧。
\item 计算$\oint_\Gamma x^2\mathrm{d}s$，其中$\Gamma$为球面$x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$被平面$x+y+z=0$所截的圆周。
\item 
\begin{multicols}{2}
计算$\int_Ly^2\mathrm{d}x$,其中\emph{L}为
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 半径为a圆心在原点的上半圆周，方向为逆时针方向。
    \item 从点\emph{A}(a,0)沿x轴到点\emph{B}(-a,0)。
\end{enumerate}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0)--(0,2)node[above]{$y$};
    \draw [->](1.5,0) arc(0:180:1.5);
    \draw (-1.5,0)node[below]{-$a$} (1.5,0)node[below]{$a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```