# How can I have two columns?

Tags: two-column

I want a simple code for building this simple effect:
[image]

Two columns: First column should contain the text and the second one should contain the image

Comment: A MWE would be helpful. Further: It is important to know your document calss you want to use. Maybe this class has a simple option for two/multi column layouts -- usually this is described in the class manual.

Comment: Is the text wrapping around the image? Or not? Is the whole document in two columns? Or only this part?

Comment: Or look at the various packages that accommodate figure placement, such as `wrapfig.`

Comment: I am using \documentclass[12pt,journal,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
can improve the code of eric?????

Comment: the whole document have one columns and where there are images 2 colomns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can archieve this for example by using `minipages`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \noindent \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{grafiken/verwendensieelearning.png}
            \caption{\label{fig:blue_rectangle} Rectangle}
        \end{figure}
    \end{minipage} \hfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more info you can find alot on `tex.stackexchange` about `minipages`

Check out [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119799/text-next-to-image) or look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234537/how-to-align-an-image-beside-a-text-in-latex?lq=1) or maybe [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55161/how-to-arrange-image-and-text-to-appear-side-by-side?lq=1) or...

Good luck =)