# Redefining and minipaging of standard environments in preamble

Tags: floats, environments, minipage

When integrating standard `LaTeX` output from a database or from software like `pandoc`, the actual content cannot be changed. To still be able to layout the document, it is important to have redefinitions in the preamble.

I am looking for preamble commands that translate (redefine layout visually) from

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{test.png}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}
```

to

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics{test.png}
\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.03\textwidth}
```

and quotations from:

```
\begin{quote}
test
\end{quote}
```

to

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
test
\end{minipage}
```

My current approach is a simple perl script that does these translations. But I want to omit in-between-operations for the sake of simplicity. 
Especially renewing the figure environment has been a big threat to me, because here I mostly do not want to renew anything (apart from removing the caption), but just enveloping a minipage around the existent figure. What are the standard approaches in the world of tex monks wisdom?

Comment: why put a figure in a minipage? That can not do anything useful.

Comment: The presented minipage figure followed by the presented minpage text results in a nice two-column arrangement of figure (left) and text (right).

Comment: No that's just two minipages, why have a figure environment inside the minipage, normally that is an error, if it doesn't give an error with H that's an oversight.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hm, I am confused, why does it then work here: [tex.stackexchange.com/a/296954/32082](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296954/32082) ? What else do you recommend to achieve figure and text side by side like in this example?

Comment: it probably works it is just doing nothing, try same without the figure env, or equivalently try the answer I posted

Comment: I took this approach from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119799/text-next-to-image . If you think there are better ways to arange figure and text side by side, please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]
  {\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}\renewcommand\caption[1][]{}}
  {\end{minipage} \hspace{0.03\textwidth}}

\renewenvironment{quote}
  {\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}}
  {\end{minipage}}
```

will do what you ask although both redefinitions seem very strange, with the new definitions, if there is not a blank line before the environment they will be set inline, and in the figure case there is one word space and one space of width `.03\textwidth` after the figure? I did not put the `figure[H]` inside the minipage as that would not do anything useful, essentially `H` just redefines `figure` to be a non-floating minipage anyway.

Comment: This solution is promising, but both minipages are neither side-by-side nor vertically aligned at top, when a `figure` environment is followed by a `quote` environment.

Comment: Your solution works if you leave out `[t]` for both commands. However, the two columns (minipages) are not vertially top-aligned anymore. Furthermore, the whole idea only works if there is not blank line between `figure` and `quote`, but this is already a problem intrinsic to the question...